# Phonegap Android create file if not exists and write to it

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems

Morning,

I am using the following to create a file on the local file system. This creates a file if it did not already exist.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
            alert("write success");
        };
        writer.write("We are testing")

    }

    function fail(error) {
        if(error.code == 1){
            alert('not found');
        }
        alert(error.code);
    }
```

However, I need to write to the file ONLY if it did not already exist.
I tried using

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
        }

function gotFS2(fileSystem) {
alert('trying again');
            fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", {create:true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
        }

function fail(error) {

            if(error.code == 1){
                alert('not found');
                gotFS2(fileSystem);
            }
            alert(error.code);
        }
```

and then calling gotFS2 if error.code == 1
but that did nothing - it didn't even create the file when it didn't exist.

It seems that gotFS2 was not called, yet `alert('not found');` in the  function fail(error)  works.

What's the easiest way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: do you pass fileSystem to gotFS2 when calling it?

Comment: @Regent: Yes. I passed fileSystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that problem is in your not saving fileSystem variable (which is in local scope in "gotFS"), so my suggestion is:

```
var savedFS;

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    savedFS = fileSystem;
    fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFS2(fileSystem) {
    alert('trying again');
    fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", { create: true }, gotFileEntry, function() {});
}

function fail(error) {
    if (error.code == 1) {
        alert('not found');
        gotFS2(savedFS);
    }
    alert(error.code);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It did not work. It seems that fail() is not being called from gotFS(fileSystem)

Comment: @Jez D i rechecked code again and also ran it - it works... Sorry for strange question, but did you delete "gotFileEntry" and "onDeviceReady" functions from code? If so, you have to get them back

Comment: its go into infinite loop

Comment: @Pravin due to call to `fail` in `gotFS2` function? Now it shouldn't. By the way, it wasn't related to question itself.